# Apache Camel: How to get the exception message inside the doCatch() block?

Tags: apache, spring-boot, apache-camel, dsl

I need to return the message from a thrown exception, or put it in the outmessage. But it does not print the correct message on the frontend.

The camel docs suggest using `.transform(simple?...)` `.handled(true)` but most of it is deprecated.

What's the correct way of doing this?

**Response:**

`<418 I'm a teapot,simple{${exception.message}},{}>`

**Route**

```
from("direct:csv")
  .doTry()
    .process(doSomeThingWithTheFileProcessor)
  .doCatch(Exception.class)
    .process(e -> {
        e.getOut().setBody(new ResponseEntity<String>(exceptionMessage().toString(), HttpStatus.I_AM_A_TEAPOT));
    }).stop()
  .end()
  .process(finalizeTheRouteProcessor);
```

**doSomethingWithFileProcessor**

```
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        String filename = exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelFileName", String.class);

        MyFile mf = repo.getFile(filename); //throws exception

        exchange.getOut().setBody(exchange.getIn().getBody());
        exchange.getOut().setHeader("CamelFileName", exchange.getIn().getHeader("CamelFileName"));
    }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a lot of ways how to do it. All of it is correct, choose your favourite depending on complexity of error handling. I have published [examples in this gist](https://gist.github.com/bedlaj/b1d16ea9710dce3a2a7652c3a714a736). None of it is deprecated in Camel version `2.22.0`.

**With Processor**

```
from("direct:withProcessor")
        .doTry()
            .process(new ThrowExceptionProcessor())
        .doCatch(Exception.class)
            .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    final Throwable ex = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Throwable.class);
                    exchange.getIn().setBody(ex.getMessage());
                }
            })
        .end();
```

**With Simple language**

```
from("direct:withSimple")
        .doTry()
            .process(new ThrowExceptionProcessor())
        .doCatch(Exception.class)
            .transform().simple("${exception.message}")
        .end();
```

**With setBody**

```
from("direct:withValueBuilder")
        .doTry()
            .process(new ThrowExceptionProcessor())
        .doCatch(Exception.class)
            .setBody(exceptionMessage())
        .end();
```

Comment: ThrowExceptionProcessor requires exception at the constructor...

Comment: @ArtemPtushkin No, it does not. `ThrowExceptionProcessor` is custom processor, not the one provided in Apache Camel. You will see link to gist, if you read answer again... https://gist.github.com/bedlaj/b1d16ea9710dce3a2a7652c3a714a736#file-dotryhandling-java-L13

Answer (score 4):

In the doCatch() Camel moves the exception into a property on the exchange with the key Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT (http://camel.apache.org/why-is-the-exception-null-when-i-use-onexception.html).

So you can use

```
e.getOut().setBody(new ResponseEntity<String>(e.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Exception.class).getMessage(), HttpStatus.OK));
```

Comment: +1 for the answer, but I chose @Bedla's answer because it's more complete and provides multiple solutions to the problem.